# Easiest way to publish AAR

Tags: android, maven, libraries, aar

I have an AAR file that I wish to publish so that anybody who wants to use my library can use it. What is an easy place to submit my AAR? Maven Central?

Every tutorial that I find is over the top complicated.

Comment: You can look into http://jitpack.io

Comment: @michaelcarrano Jitpack builds the code for you. What if I already have the built AAR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jCenter is the default repository used with Android's gradle plugin and is run by bintray.com. The advantage is that users do not need to add additional repositories to their config, they only need to add the dependency to your library.

There are comprehensive guides about how to publish on jCenter, for instance here https://www.virag.si/2015/01/publishing-gradle-android-library-to-jcenter/ and here https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en